# Symfony can't display float number

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a Symfony `product` entity mapped with Doctrine.

My column price is defined like that :

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2)
  */
 private $price;
```

In PhpMyAdmin, on one of my products, i define the price to be 59.99. But when i display it in my template i can't have the entire number and i have only 59. 
I tried doing this :

```
{{  product.price|number_format(2) }}
```

but it displays 59.00.. the dump gives me the same thing.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Welcometo Stackoverflow @Strange_nh . Could you say us, how data are stored in database? When you verify data in your table, it is stored as 59.00 or 59.99? For currency value, you should store data with the decimal type

Comment: Thanks for your welcoming comment !
When i verify in my database it's stored as 59.99. I just changed it to decimal type but i have the same issue.

Comment: Try `{{ dump(product.price)}}` to know what is returned by your getter?  Then edit your question to provide us the result and edit it too to add the getter of price.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreTranchant, it was my product.price getter. I posted  my answer to update my question. Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: Go to product.php entity file , and check your getters/setters make sure its float there.. then update the database schema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @AlexandreTranchant, my `product.price` getter was like that

```
public function getPrice(): ?int
{
    return $this->price;
}
```

so it allowed me to store only integer and not float/decimal number.
Changed it to float and I have my entire decimal number.

Comment: Thanks it did the trick for me too . I also had to change my setter since the parameter was also typed with "int" instead of "float".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you loose the decimals but i prefer to use type decimal:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $price;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed it but as expected i still have the same issue..

Comment: which character is used for the decimal? a dot or another character like a comma?

Comment: I used a dot : `59.99`

Comment: your sure you got the same database, table and record as where you set the value? 
What happens if you use a select query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i am yes. Another problem is that if i update the price using EasyAdmin, the price stays at 59.00 in my product list.. If i use a select query in PhpMyAdmin i have 59.99